# How to disable certain check_boxes when using Formtastic's :as => :check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @admin] do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :email, :as => :email %>
        <%= f.input :password, :as => :password %>
        <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :as => :password %>
        <%= f.input :admin_roles, :as => :check_boxes, :required => true, :disabled => [1] %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

-

```
<%= f.input :admin_roles, :as => :check_boxes, :required => true, :disabled => [1] %>
```

Passing an array to the above code disables the checkbox with id=1, which is nice. But I want to check the model of each checkbox, too see if it has a specific value, so I can disable it or not.

```
do_not_disable_checkbox if admin_role.do_not_show_me_boolean_field
```

Do I need to iterate each of my :admin_roles and output a checkbox for each? Or can I do it in one line like above? I'm new to rails and ruby, and I can't wrap my head around it and hoping for some help to put me in the right direction.